# Why does English use the French "sans" for sans serif?

Tags: etymology, phrase-origin, typography, french

Is it because France had impactful printers and typecutters like the Garamonds and Jensons in the Renaissance?

Or is it about being elegant and “Frenchified” when talking about something as peculiar and slightly arcane as typography? (Like Jacques in Shakespeare’s *Much Ado About Nothing*, picking “sans” for the sake of rhythm…).

Serifs, after all, comes from the Dutch. So why “sans” and not just “without” serif? German, e.g., does have the option of “serifenlos”, and Italian “senza grazie” (grazie referring to serifs). German and Italian also call this category “Grotesk”/grottesco.

Comment: Hello, Florence. There is a very relevant (if doubtless unwelcome) comment about this from OED, found in the [Online Etymological Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sans-serif).

Comment: As the [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sans) says, "sans" in English long precedes "sans serif".

Comment: More specifically, I'd guess that someone thought "serif" was French (the occurrence of various Frenchified forms like ceriph) and therefore assumed "sans" to be the natural prefix. But there doesn't seem to be evidence.

Comment: *Tout ce qui est dit en français semble élevé.*

Comment: Also be happy that the font names were not translated around the world ;-) See also [Sans Souci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanssouci); it seems French was quite "en vogue" in the times of [Napoleon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon).

Comment: How does "serif, after all, come from Dutch"? The Dutch commonly use "schreefloos" for "sans serif", and "serif" is not used anywhere else, as far as I know.

Answer (score 17):

The short answer is that we don't know for sure. *Sans serif* is a compound formed in English between the long-used English preposition from French *sans* and *serif*, most likely invented by printers creating new typefaces.

### Dictionary

Oxford English Dictionary, "[serif, n. and adj.](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/serif_n?tab=meaning_and_use#23337811)" gives an explanation that mentions the term *sanserif*:

> Any of the cross-strokes or finishing strokes at the end of a principal stroke of a letter. Cf. sanserif n.

Many of the early spellings (late 18th, early 19th century) are inconsistent: *ceriph* and *surriph* show up as early forms. *Serif* as a spelling shows up sometime in the 19th century. Also, the word is Dutch in origin: *schreef* means a line or a stroke.

Meanwhile, *[sanserif](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/sanserif_n?tab=meaning_and_use#24514100)* appears in the 19th century, sometimes as *san-serif*, sometimes *sans-surryphs* or *sans-ceriph* before the spelling stabilizes as *sans serif*:

> A form of type without serifs: called also grotesque. Also attributive. Cf. serif n.

### Context in Printing

While sans serif typefaces were already around, London printer Vincent Figgins published the first known mention of "sans-serif" in his *Specimen of Printing Types*. The OED lists 1830 as the first use; here is one page from the 1834 edition, [via Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/b2874231x/page/n175/mode/2up):

[image]

The use is jargony. The entire book has typefaces with labels referring to size (e.g., "twenty line pica," "two-line great primer") as well as form (e.g., "antique," "sans-serif," "perspective"). Figgins's jargon would soon seep into other guides. Here is [Alexander Wilson, c. 1842](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Specimen_of_Two_line_Letter_Book_and_New/HGIxAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=sans%20serif&pg=PP69&printsec=frontcover):

[image]

By 1842, the word was already in use in debates about which font is more appropriate for the visually impaired (*[Statements of the Education, Employments, and Internal Arrangements, Adopted at the Asylum for the Blind, Glasgow](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Statements_of_the_Education_Employments/oVXM527YRN8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=sans%20serif&pg=PA54&printsec=frontcover)*):

> Dr. Fry's alphabet is the *sans-serif*, of type-founders,-- plain roman capitals, merely deprived of the small strokes at their extremities.

### Speculation

Why would a printer combine a French-original preposition with a Dutch-original stem? We could make a few guesses. The preposition *[sans](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/sans_prep?tab=etymology#24512242)* was already in English, and it has sometimes been used for non-French words - *sans delay*. It is quite possible that the people who first used it saw *serif* as a technical term - or even mistakenly thought it was a French one - and felt *sans* was more appropriate to use with *serif*. Also, there may be an argument from form: more words are formed from *sans* than from *without*, illustrating how open the two prepositions are to forming new words. (22 words headed by *sans* in the OED and 3 headed by *without*.) In any case, it's hard to say for sure. Word formation can be an arbitrary and idiosyncratic process.

Comment: *sans délai* is French

Comment: @Henry "Sans teeth, sans eyes, sans taste, sans everything", in As You Like It, are all non-French words ;-)

Comment: @Henry True. I was misled by the English spelling. I could have also used *sans wings* or *sans prick* or *sans aircraft*, looking at some of the examples in the OED.

Comment: To add to the speculation, the Dutch use "schreefloos", and English has the equivalent "-less" suffix. "serifless" would have made perfect sense. The fact it's not used indicates that the "sans serif" was not borrowed from Dutch.

Comment: Maybe the alliteration sounds better than aserif or serifless.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: How about "serif-bereft"? XD

Comment: @user21820 Ooh, painful. IMO, *no* ;)

Comment: "the word is Dutch in origin": I don't buy it.  Where did the second syllable come from?  _Schreef_ sounds basically like "scrape" but with fricatives instead of stops.  Dutch _sch-_ words tend to come into English with sc- as in scow and scupper.

Comment: @phoog Compare *ship* and *shoal*, Dutch words that did not become [sc-] in English. It's plausible for the word to have another form: *jeer* (poss. from German *scheren*.  Here's what the OED says: "It has been suggested (W. W. Skeat in Notes & Queries 9th Ser. vol. 5 (1900) 345/2) that the spellings with initial cer- or ser- attempt to represent the pronunciation /sx/ of the initial consonant cluster sch in the Dutch noun."

Answer (score 4):

> **sanserif** (n.)
>
> A form of type without serifs: called also grotesque. Also
> attributive. Cf. serif n.
>
> **1830** Lines Pica San-Serif.
> *Figgins's Spec. Printing Types* 8
>
> **1976** Sans serif, to him, was the best, if not the only kind of type suitable for the modern world.
> *Visible Language* vol. X. 88
>
> Etymology
>
> **Probably formed within English, by compounding**.
> **Etymons**: sans prep., serif n.
>
> Probably < **sans** *prep*. + **serif** n.
>
> **Notes**
>
> The word *serif*, however, has not hitherto been found till much later
> than the first appearance of *sanserif*, and it has been suggested
> that it may have been evolved from the supposed compound.
> [OED]

> **sans** (prep.)
>
> Without. Now *archaic* (chiefly with reminiscence of Shakespeare), *jocular*, and Heraldry.
>
> Before the time of Shakespeare used almost exclusively with nouns
> adopted from Old French, in collocations already formed in that
> language, as **sans delay, sans doubt, sans fable, sans pity, sans
> return**. Even in some of our earliest examples, however, a native
> English synonym has been substituted for the Romanic noun in the
> phrase, as in sans biding = **sans delay**.
>
> **c1300** Of gold he made a table Al ful of steorren, saun fable.
> *Kyng Alisaunder* 134
> [OED]

---

> The word "serif" is more easily illustrated than described. The
> ordinary roman capitals (...) have serifs; the characters known to
> sign-painters as "block letters" (...) do not posses them, and are
> called by printers **"sans-serif," or without serifs, a form which
> would suggested a French origin were it not that in the fifteen century
> "sans" was as good English as French**. The etymology of the word is
> wholly unknown, and its uncertainty in this respect is emphasized by
> the fact that scarcely any two authorities spell it alike.
> [R.
> Coupland Harding—*On Kerns and Serifs* in Transactions of the Royal
> Society of New Zealand, Vol. 29, p.97](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Transactions/9gY1AQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=origin%20of%20the%20term%20sans%20serif&pg=PA97&printsec=frontcover) (1896)

> In typography and lettering a *sans-serif, gothic*, or simply *sans*
> letterform is one that does not have extending features called
> "serifs" at the end of strokes. The term comes from the French word,
> meaning "without" and "serif" of uncertain origin, possible from the
> Dutch word *schreef* meaning "line" or "pen stroke." San-serif fonts are often used for headings rather than for body text. They are also used to convey simplicity and modernity or minimalism.
> [E. Buky et al.;
> *The Copyeditor's Workbook*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Copyeditor_s_Workbook/kAuIDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=origin%20of%20the%20term%20sans%20serif&pg=PA22&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

> The word "serif" is itself modern, not ancient; it is first found in
> nineteenth-century typefounders' catalogues from England...and is of
> unsure etymology. "Sans serif," in fact has been found to precede the
> word "serif" in chronological usage.
> [Patricia Butz; *The Art of the
> Hekatompedon Inscription and the Birth of the Stoikhedon Style*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Art_of_the_Hekatompedon_Inscription/2uB5DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=origin%20of%20the%20term%20sans%20serif&pg=PA10&printsec=frontcover)
> (2010)

Answer (score -1):

Probably because "sans" is sorta English, "la belle dame sans merci" being well know, and adapted/used in other context.  "Sans x" isn't that common, but it's not really that unknown either.

Comment: W.Shakespeare, on the last of the 'seven ages of Man': _Last scene of all,
That ends this strange eventful history,
Is second childishness and mere oblivion;
Sans teeth, sans eyes, sans taste, sans everything._

Answer (score -1):

Unless Will the Quill was trying to flaunt his knowledge of the latest loan-words, English took sans unto itself long before Shakespeare sprinkled it so happily around the stage (eg: in *All the World's a Stage*, from *As You Like It*)

Etymonline, eg, suggests 'sans' became Anglicised at least a century before Will wrapped his quill round it.

Given that English court Norman French had used the term since the Conquest, and it came from that Latin which had been the lingua-franca of Europe's rulers and intelligentsia from hundreds of years earlier and remained so for centuries after, why is its etymology worth enquiring about?

Comment: Someone having kindly reminded SE of this topic, today seems a good time to tell you it was only a couple of days after the Question was Posted before I heard several uses of 'sans' in every-day English on BBC Radio 4, one being in a casual remark by one of The Archers. By the way, I guess SE reminded me of the topic because some brave soul Down-voted my Answer. It's not for my own sake I say Down-voters should be compelled to give reasons, even in anonymity. Who sees a reason for my Down-vote other than calling Shakespeare 'Will the Quill'?